# Return the first element or None from filter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a convenient way to return the first element or `None` from `filter`?

```
filter(lambda x: x == 5, [3, 5, 5, 8]) # ?? 5
filter(lambda x: x == 35, [3, 5, 5, 8]) # ?? None
```

instead of having to call `list()` and then `[0]`?

My question is about the method `filter` and not list comprehension.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`filter` objects are essentially iterators. Just use the `next` function to get the first value:

```
next(filter(lambda x: x == 35, [3, 5, 5, 8]), None)
```

`next(it, None)` will return `None` if `next(it)` raises `StopIteration`.